# Resizing CSS Device

Tags: html, css, mobile

I'm using an iPhone CSS device from https://marvelapp.github.io/devices.css/

However, I can't find an intelligent way to make it resize to fit within mobile devices. The only way I've found is by changing the meta viewport's initial scale, but that changes how the entire Bootstrap website appears on mobile, not just the mobile device obviously.

Is there a way to perhaps change the scale for the specific div within which the CSS mockup resides, or another way to make the device resize for mobile view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `transform: scale()` seems to work.

The `scale` could be set using JS based on the viewport width to make it fit the screen.

```css
.small {
  transform: scale(0.5);
}
```

```html
<link href="//marvelapp.github.io/devices.css/assets/devices.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="marvel-device iphone6 silver">
    <div class="top-bar"></div>
    <div class="sleep"></div>
    <div class="volume"></div>
    <div class="camera"></div>
    <div class="sensor"></div>
    <div class="speaker"></div>
    <div class="screen">
        <!-- Content goes here -->
    </div>
    <div class="home"></div>
    <div class="bottom-bar"></div>
</div>

<div class="marvel-device iphone6 silver small">
    <div class="top-bar"></div>
    <div class="sleep"></div>
    <div class="volume"></div>
    <div class="camera"></div>
    <div class="sensor"></div>
    <div class="speaker"></div>
    <div class="screen">
        <!-- Content goes here -->
    </div>
    <div class="home"></div>
    <div class="bottom-bar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Amazing answer, thank you, I was unaware of the transform option.  This works best so far, I'll use media queries to toggle such a class for the device, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You must to do it manually using "medias" to determine how it should look in certain devices. [Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) are useful to make breakpoints on viewport sizes to adjust content and view it properly on different screen resolutions.

The following example shows how a media query changes some existing values de `.marvel-device.iphone6` and `.marvel-device.iphone6 .sensor` at a resolution of 320px wide.

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
    .marvel-device.iphone6{
        width: 320px; /*Or the new width you want in pixels*/
        height: 480px; /*Or the new height you want in pixels*/
    }
    .marvel-device.iphone6 .sensor{
        left: 50px; /*Or the left position for the sensor*/
    }
}
```

As I said before, I don't know an other better way to do it but manually, so you need to copy that code, and modify these values to fit the screen resolutions you want. Unless you could use transform for the whole `.marvel-device`